# Notepad++ to Unix timeshare Transfer issues

Tags: java, notepad++

So I have a code that appears like it would have perfect formatting in Notepad++, but when I login to my Unix timeshare, open vim, and paste the code into the newly created file, it later has problems compiling. I keep getting "class, interface, or enum expected" errors, however my code appears to have the right amount of brackets and such. I've even tried using Filezilla to transfer my java file in to my unix folder, but I get the same errors. Does anybody else experience problems while transferring code from Notepad++ to Unix? If so, is there a way I can fix this? I've provided my code below; it is meant to find the roots of an entered polynomial using the bisection method:

```
import java.util.*;

  class Roots {

  public static int degree;
  public static double[] coArrayC;
  public static double[] coArrayD;
  public static int coeffiNumb;

  public static void main( String[] args ){
        double resolution = 0.01;
        double threshold = 0.001;
        double tolerance = 0.0000001;
        
        double rightEndPt;          
        double leftEndPt;


        int polyRootPointer = 0;
        int diffRootPointer = 0;

        boolean rootAns = false;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Enter the degree: ");
        degree = sc.nextInt();
        
        coeffiNumb = degree + 1;
        System.out.print("Enter " + coeffiNumb + " coefficients: ");
        double[] coefficients = new double[coeffiNumb];
        
        coArrayC = new double[coeffiNumb];
        double[] rootArray = new double[degree];
        coArrayD = new double[coeffiNumb];
        double[] rootArrayDeriv = new double[degree];
        for(int i = 0; i < coeffiNumb; i++) {
              coefficients[i] = sc.nextDouble();
        }
        System.out.print("Enter the lower and upper endpoints, in that order: ");
        leftEndPt = sc.nextDouble();
        rightEndPt = sc.nextDouble();

        diff(coefficients);

        for (double i = leftEndPt; i < rightEndPt-resolution; i = i + resolution){
              if (isPositive(coArrayD, i) != isPositive(coArrayD, i+resolution) || isPositive(coArrayD, i) == 0) {
                    rootArrayDeriv[diffRootPointer] = findRoot(coArrayD, i, i+resolution, tolerance);
                    diffRootPointer++;
              }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rootArrayDeriv.length; i++) {
              double tempVal;
              tempVal = poly(coefficients, rootArrayDeriv[i]);
              tempVal = Math.abs(tempVal);
              if (tempVal < threshold) {
                    rootArray[polyRootPointer] = rootArrayDeriv[i];
                    polyRootPointer++;
                    rootAns = true;
              }
        }

        for (double i = leftEndPt; i < rightEndPt-resolution; i = i + resolution){
              if (isPositive(coefficients, i) != isPositive(coefficients, i+resolution) || isPositive(coefficients, i) == 0) {
                    rootArray[polyRootPointer] = findRoot(coefficients, i, i+resolution, tolerance);
                    polyRootPointer++;
                    rootAns = true;
              }
        }

        Arrays.sort(rootArray);

        if (rootAns == false) {
              System.out.println("Sorry - no roots were found at that particular interval.");
                    }
              }
        } else {
              for (int i = 0; i < rootArray.length; i++) {
                    if (rootArray[i] != 0.0) {
                          System.out.printf("Root found at %.5f%n", Arrays.sort(rootArray));                  
        }
  }

  static double poly(double[] C, double x){
        double polySum = 0;
        coArrayC[0] = C[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < coArrayC.length; i++){
              coArrayC[i] = C[i]*(Math.pow(x, i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < coArrayC.length; i++){
              polySum = polySum + coArrayC[i];
        }
        return(polySum);

  }

  static double[] diff(double[] C){ 
        for (int i = 0; i < degree; i++){
              coArrayD[i] = (i+1)*C[i+1];
        }
        return(coArrayD);
  }

  static double findRoot(double[] C, double a, double b, double tolerance){
        double root = 0.0 , residual;
        while ( Math.abs(b - a) > tolerance ) {
              root = (a + b) / 2.0;
              residual = poly(C, root);
              if (poly(C, a) > 0 && poly(C, b) < 0) {
                    if (residual > 0)
                          a = root;
                    else
                          b = root;
              } else if (poly(C, a) < 0 && poly(C, b) > 0) {
                    if (residual > 0)
                          b = root;
                    else
                          a = root;
              }
        }
        return(root);
  }

  static int isPositive(double[] C, double a){
        double endpointTempA;
        endpointTempA = poly(C, a);
        if (endpointTempA < 0) {
              return(1);
        } else if (endpointTempA > 0) {
              return(2);
        } else {
              return(0); 
        }
  }
```

}

[image: EDIT: here's what my errors are, pretty much]

Comment: what sort of problems do you have?

Comment: Make your class to be "public" --> public class Roots

Comment: If you suspect problem with notepad++, create a small test class; get it onto target; compile there.

Comment: between line 77 and 81 you are closing a lot of brackets after if (rootAns == false). Your problem is probably here.

Comment: from lines 81-137, I keep getting "class, interface, or enum expected" errors. I'll try to attach a pic of that in the question.

Comment: by the way Arnaud Potier, you were right. However, that only cut a few of the errors in my code. Perhaps the brackets are just askew?